# Dialog Box instead of Context Menu

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I have a program that displays a list of records pulled from a database through a content provider.

I have a content menu that appears on when a long click is pressed on any item on the list view, which gives the option to delete the item.

What I want to do is use a Dialog box instead - that way the user has the option to mark the item with a description before it is deleted.

Here is the code for my content menu:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
showDialog(DIALOG_SAB_PRIORITY_ID);
menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, "Returned Item - Remove");

}
```

And the code for when the item is selected:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case DELETE_ID:

        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(BorrowMeContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/"
                + info.id);
        getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
        fillData();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

I should mention that I'm going to change the item so it isn't deleted, just marked as returned. My Dialog box is as follows:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog dialog;
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_SAB_PRIORITY_ID:
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Good Condition", "Bad Condition" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Returned Item Condition:")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            // This is the listener that checks to see what
                            // radio button is clicked
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int item) {
                                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                // Integer.toString(item),
                                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                if (item == 0) {
                                    // If item returned in good condition
                                    goodBadSwitch = false;
                                } else if (item == 1) {
                                    // If item is returned in bad condition
                                    goodBadSwitch = true;
                                }

                            }
                        })
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            // This is the listener for the button to
                            // dismiss the dialog box
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {



                                dialog.dismiss();



                            }

                        });

        dialog = builder.create();

        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

So far all this code does is call the menu after the dialog box. I just want the dialog box to take the place of the menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get rid off menu context then you could move the call of your dialog to your list view `onListItemClick` listener, something like this:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // other code...
    showDialog(DIALOG_SAB_PRIORITY_ID);
    // other code...
}
```

Comment: For anyone interested - this is a great article that goes further with what was recommended here. Thanks again! http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/click-long-press-event-listeners-list-activity/

Comment: you're welcome... the article has some good tips for customizing actions... regards!